# Image upload error in Laravel

Tags: php, image, laravel

I am trying to upload a image to database but it's giving me the:Can't write image data to path (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/agrohelp/public/uploads/buletine/1504966392.jpeg)"
error

here is the code:

```
$buletin=$request->file('buletin');
$filename = time().'.'.$buletin->getClientOriginalExtension();
Image::make($buletin)->resize(300,300)->save(public_path('/uploads/buletine/'.$filename)); 

$employee->buletin=$filename;
```

Comment: Most probably permission issue. Which OS you are using?

Comment: i am using macOS Sierra

Comment: Give 777 permission to your buletine folder and it should work.

Comment: how to give the 777 permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And Try Like This:

**Check The Permissions:**
 - permission images/articles 777

```
Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(300,300)->save('public/uploads/bulentine'.$filename);
```

**Give The Permissions Like This:**

**Use `CHMOD`**

> For Your Recursive file

```
chmod -R 777 foldername or pathname
```

> For Non Recursive file

```
chmod 777 foldername or pathname
```

Comment: `chmod 777 thumbs`

Comment: @Andrei .. Okz fine ... Thumps Up if You get the ans :)